# Convert 2 arrays to 1 hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4]

array2 = [true,false,true,false]

expected output : [:1 => true, :2 => false, :3 => true, :4 => false]
```

Would like to make the `array1` values as keys of the hash and `array2` values as the hash values.

Using **ruby 1.8**

Can someone please help how to achieve this.

Comment: Is the array1 just numbers in ascending order?

Comment: @Severin: array1 here is just an example but in my case its a string and can be anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
output = Hash[array1.zip(array2)]
```

Comment: Perfect, works fine with the example i provided in my question. But doesn't work if the values are same in array1 = [1,1,1,1] returns {1=>false}

Comment: @Ross Hash key should be unique, what is the expected result when array1 is `[1,1,1,1]` ?